Self-signed certificate doesn't work in Chrome
I created example.dev self-signed certificate, added it as trusted to the Mac Keychain.
Both curl and Safari show https://example.dev as legal, but Chrome reports net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error.
curl -v https://example.dev output:
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=IL; ST=Israel; O=example.dev; OU=example.dev; CN=example.dev
*  start date: Nov  8 05:02:56 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Nov  8 05:02:56 2025 GMT
*  common name: example.dev (matched)
*  issuer: C=IL; ST=Israel; O=example.dev; OU=example.dev; CN=example.dev
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* using HTTP/1.x
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.dev



There are not sufficient details known about the certificate, but likely the subject alternative name is missing

@SteffenUllrich - thank you, I tried with alternative as well, w/o success:
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout example.dev.key -out example.dev.crt -subj "/CN=example.dev" -addext "subjectAltName=DNS:example.dev,DNS:example.dev,IP:127.0.0.1"

Works for me if the certificate is properly imported as a trusted CA. Unknown what you are doing different and what error you get exactly.
